# Pandas correlation table limited to m columns by n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I know how to create a (lovely) Pandas correlation table, ranked by correlation:

```
c = df.corr().abs()
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
s = c.unstack()
so = s.order(kind="quicksort")
pprint(so)
```

This is great.

The issue is, this outputs the correlations for the full matrix of values -- for all columns x all columns, in a cross matrix.

But what if I just want to check one column, say, `df['m']`, for its correlations across all other columns?

Do I need to create two dataframes and check the correlations between them? Is there a faster script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could just slice the `corr()` `DataFrame` like:

```
c = df.corr()['m'].abs()
so = c.sort_values(kind='quicksort')
print(so)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply loop through the columns of `df` and build a Series out of the correlations:

```
result = (pd.Series([df['m'].corr(df[col]) for col in df], index=df.columns)
          .abs().sort_values())
```

If you plan to do this for many columns, it may be quicker to calculate the entire correlation matrix and use `.loc` to select the rows of interest: `so.loc['m']`.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)), columns=list('klmn'))
result = (pd.Series([df['m'].corr(df[col]) for col in df], index=df.columns)
          .abs().sort_values())
print(result)
# l    0.041438
# n    0.086255
# k    0.393375
# m    1.000000
# dtype: float64

c = df.corr().abs()
s = c.unstack()
so = s.sort_values()  # s.order is deprecated. use s.sort_values
print(so.loc['m'])
# l    0.041438
# n    0.086255
# k    0.393375
# m    1.000000
# dtype: float64
```

Note `result` and `so.loc['m']` are the same.